# TypeScript 2 - @types not recognized

Tags: typescript

Due to legal barriers we have our node_modules in another folder(lets call it "external"), so following sentence from TS docs does not apply: **"Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on"**.

I believe that is so, because my folder is in ./external/node_modules and not ./node_modules.

So can this somehow work? I tried that way as well:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./external/node_modules/@types"]
}
```

Folder structure:

```
- external
-- node_modules
--- @types
- tsconfig.json
```

Now when I try to import angular I receive "Cannot find module angular" error message.

Comment: Basically import of angular just does not work("Cannot find module angular").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the compiler can't actually find the module.
The compiler is looking for both the module and the definition file for it, so it's not enough to specify the `typeRoots`, you probably also need to set the `baseUrl` in the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Base directory to resolve non-relative module names

As it's written in the [Module Resolution baseUrl section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url):

> Using a baseUrl is a common practice in applications using AMD module
>   loaders where modules are “deployed” to a single folder at run-time.
>   The sources of these modules can live in different directories, but a
>   build script will put them all together.
>
> Setting baseUrl informs the compiler where to find modules. All module
>   imports with non-relative names are assumed to be relative to the
>   baseUrl.

---

#### Edit

I've never been in your scenario, so this more of a guess...
But looking at the steps described in the docs about module resolution:

> a non-relative import will follow the Node.js resolution logic, first
>   looking up a file, then looking up an applicable folder. So import { b
>   } from "moduleB" in source file /src/moduleA.ts would result in the
>   following lookups:
>
> 1. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.ts
> 2. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.tsx
> 3. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
> 4. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
> 5. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
> 6. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
> 7. /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts
> 8. /root/node_modules/moduleB.ts
> 9. /root/node_modules/moduleB.tsx
> 10. /root/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
> 11. /root/node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
> 12. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
> 13. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
> 14. /root/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts
> 15. /node_modules/moduleB.ts
> 16. /node_modules/moduleB.tsx
> 17. /node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
> 18. /node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
> 19. /node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
> 20. /node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
> 21. /node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts

It seems that it shouldn't be looking in `./external/...`

Comment: That could be the case, but the correct base url in my case is default( "." ). Or is it? I added folder structure to question

Comment: Btw, if I add absolute path to typeRoots it is working fine.

Comment: Interesting.  Also, check out my revised answer.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1055